# More efficient way of creating sql table other than using Union

Tags: sql, group-by, union, toad-data-point

I have a table like this:

```
EmployeeID  Gender  Is leader   Is officer
------------------------------------------
1             F     
2             M          Y           Y
3             M     
4             M     
5             F          Y  
6             F     
7             M     
8             M          Y
9             M          Y            Y
10            F
```

And I'd like to create a table like this:

```
Row_Number  Category    M   F
------------------------------
     1      Leader      2   1
     2      Officer     3   0
     3      Total       5   1
```

Using code like this:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS row_number, ' Leader' AS Category,
    M+F AS Total, 
    SUM(IIF(Gender = 'M' AND `Is Leader` = 'Yes', 1, 0)) AS M, 
    SUM(IIF(Gender = 'F' AND `Is Leader` = 'Yes', 1, 0)) AS F
FROM 
    table

UNION

(SELECT 
     2 AS row_number, ' Officer' AS Category,
     M+F AS Total, 
     SUM(IIF(Gender = 'M' AND `Is Officer` = 'Yes', 1, 0)) AS M, 
     SUM(IIF(Gender = 'F' AND `Is Officer` = 'Yes', 1, 0)) AS F
 FROM 
     table
)

UNION

(SELECT 
     3 AS row_number, ' Total' AS Category,
     M+F as Total, 
     SUM(IIF(Gender = 'M', 1, 0)) AS M, 
     SUM(IIF(Gender = 'F', 1, 0)) AS F
 FROM 
     table
)
```

Is there a better way to create the table other than using UNION? Is that possible to customize groups and then do group by directly?